# Copy Site Column values to SharePoint Group

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have site column called users based of people and groups and for example it has 4 users separated by semicolon.

Questions:
1) Can I copy the values from users site column to site permissions owner group.

2) How can i split users into multiple lines from users site columns, currently it is in one line with semicolon.

I really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of below code you can values from people sitecolumn and play as you want

```
SPList oList = new SPSite("http://devbox1:71").AllWebs["PCS"].GetList("http://devebox:71/PCS/Lists/UserList");

SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.Items;         
SPListItem itemFound;         
if (oList.EnableVersioning)         
{             
    foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)             
    {                  
        string[] strName;
        string str = oListItem["UserField"].ToString();
        strName=str.Split('#');                 
        Console.Write(strName[0]);
     }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll have two memory leaks using this code sample. One for the SPSite & one for the SPWeb objects you open up.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SPGroup group = web.AssociatedOwnerGroup;
SPFieldUserValueCollection users = 
    new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, item["users"] as string);
foreach (SPFieldUserValue user in users)
{
    if (null != user.User) 
    {
        group.AddUser(user.User);
    }
}
group.Update();
```